# How to create a responsive layout of elements with coherent width?

Tags: html, css

I use a responsive layout that displays elements with a coherent width. Depending on the width of the screen, the element rows are wrapped.

The example under https://jsfiddle.net/jo6rt09k/ shows what I expect as visual result.

However, I believe that my way is not the right one and there is certainly a better implementation or newer CSS rules to achieve what I want.

My questions therefore are:

- Is it possible and if so how to avoid the media queries?
- Is it possible and if so how to use `min-width` and `max-width` to achive the same result?
- Is it possible and if so how to realize the margin without using
  the `calc` function?

Comment: honestly, I think your implementation is good. If you use sass, If you want, I can give you some mixins I coded and use a lot to do the thing, but the basic idea is the same. Probably you could do something similar with the use of css-tables or the new Grid rules, but the former is an old fashioned way, the latter is too new ;)

Comment: Yeah, but instead of calc you can use percentage margins. Personally, I wouldn't mind using calc because support is rather good